# Using dpkg in multi thread decompression

Tags: c, dpkg

I have the following problem , i need to run installation process using DPKG but on all CPU cores , all i can find are ways to compress the files using pixz after dpkg source code modification but absolutly nothing about decompression instalation it self.

Do anyone did sth like that ? or is there some more detailed description/documentation of dpkg source code ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to missing multi-threaded support in liblzma upstream, but this has landed there already. A release of liblzma has also been made, it just needs to be uploaded to Debian. Once that's done, I've already got the code to make dpkg use the multi-threaded decompression support for xz. It should not be too long now I guess. But that will only hit Debian unstable/testing until the next stable release happens.